# SonicWall, Google Fiber for business, and static IPs

Tags: google, sonicwall, static-ip, fiber

I recently had to switch a SonicWall over to Google Fiber's business offering and am trying to figure out how to configure one of the 5 static IPs to point to the router itself.

Google Fiber's static IPs work by assigning a dynamic IP to the WAN port via DHCP. They then serve your block of 5 static IPs to the Fiber Jack, which the SonicWall can simply assign as public/private Address Objects that are connected to their respective internal devices via NAT Policies and Access Rules.

The trouble I'm running into is assigning one of the static IPs so that it points to the current WAN interface so it can be used for VPN access. I can get the VPN to work using the dynamic IP address assigned by Google, but I don't want to have to configure DDNS just to ensure VPN access is always available. I feel like this should be simple, but I just can't seem to find the necessary step to make it work.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will either need a separate gateway device between the handoff (I like to use a little 8 port layer 3 switch) and the SonicWALL or you will need to configure the SonicWALL with a second network to use your static assignment on.

Please see the diagram shown here to see the second solution:
https://support.google.com/fiber/answer/6136162?hl=en

Comment: Thanks, Nathan. I recognize what I need to do, it's more of a "How do I do that?" that I'm trying to discover. I have found plenty of guides to doing this with other gateways, but no one has written a guide for the SonicWall that I can see.

I was hoping there was a way to do it without creating a VLAN on that WAN port, but that may not be the case. I will have to test that.

Thanks again!